# What's the shortcut for "small caps" with TextMate4?

Tags: small-caps, textmate

I've looked for this online for some time, but none of the various TextMate cheat sheets provide a shortcut rather than simply writing `\textsc{X}`. I'd like to highlight some block of text and make it into small caps.

http://g-design.net/textmate.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut is: ⇧⌘K in TextMate.